# How do i add a searchbar to my custom map?

Tags: html, dictionary

I have made my own custom google map. I am new to html code. Here is my map's html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<iframe
  width="950"
  height="600"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?key=AIzaSyC1mB-lVTZ8gkRUL4rWwDkJg2k0H9A7pXk
    &q=coffee">
</iframe>
</html>
```

I would like to add a searchbar just like this one [Google Maps JavaScript API v3: Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

How would I merge the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a searchbar directly to the map is not possible when you use an iframe.

when you want to work with google maps it is recommend to learn a bit more about it.
This is a link to the Google Map Developer Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?hl=en

at least you can find the solution here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=en